# Finding the group average in an array in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I'm trying to find the group average for the maximum and minimum value.
Below is my data store.

```
items{
   0:
      {
      data:{
            USERS: 5
            USAGE: 10.5
           }
       }
    1:
      {
      data:{
            USERS: 5
            USAGE: 15
           }
       }
     2:
      {
      data:{
            USERS: 1
            USAGE: 20
           }
       }
}
```

I wanna find the group average with respect to USERS for minimum and maximum.
So the final result should be :

```
result{
  0: {
    USERS: 5
    USAGE: 12.75 /* i.e (15+10.5) / 2 */
  }
  1:{
    USERS: 1
    USAGE: 20
  }

}
```

Sorry for my bad explanation and English.

Comment: please add the code, you tried - and the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be more specific with your problem. But I will try to help you.

In general if you want to find the average in an array you could use something like this.

```
        let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];  
        let sum = 0;

        Ext.Array.each(arr, function(item, index, arrItSelf) {
            sum += item;
        });

        let average = sum / arr.length;

        console.log(average);
```

If your basing your question of a Collection (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.util.Collection.html) then you could use something like this:

```
        let coll = new Ext.util.Collection

        coll.items = [{
            users: 5,
            usage: 10.5
        }, {
            users: 5,
            usage: 15
        }, {
            users: 1,
            usage: 20
        }];

        console.log(coll.average('usage'));
        console.log(coll.max('usage'));
```

I hope I could help you.

**EDIT:**

You could also create a store for your records and then group them and use the same functionality as the collection above.

*Example:*

```
        let store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
            'users',
            'usage'
        ], 
        data: [{
            users: 5,
            usage: 10.5
        }, {
            users: 5,
            usage: 15
        }, {
            users: 1,
            usage: 20
        }, {
            users: 2,
            usage: 15
        }, {
            users: 3,
            usage: 26
        }, {
            users: 4,
            usage: 13
        }],
        groupField: 'users'
    });

    console.log(store.average('usage', true));

    console.log(store.max('usage', true));
```

Comment: I understand that you did not get my question, let me rephrase it for you.
So let's say there are multiple records for users:1,2,3...8

What I need is the average usage column where users:1 and also users:8

Comment: I edited my post. Maybe using a store for your records and grouping them is what you need? I created a sencha fiddle for you to test as well.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31f8

Comment: Thanks, man. It worked. I used something similar to your suggestion.

Comment: Glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all value in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and render the wanted result by getting the average grouped by `USERS`.

```js
const
    mapIt = (map, { data: { USERS, USAGE } }) => {
        var temp = map.get(USERS) || { USERS, sum: 0, count: 0 };
        temp.sum += USAGE;
        temp.count++;
        return map.set(USERS, temp);
    };


var items = { 0: { data: { USERS: 5, USAGE: 10.5 } }, 1: { data: { USERS: 5, USAGE: 15 } }, 2: { data: { USERS: 1, USAGE: 20 } } },
    result = Object.assign({}, Array.from(
        Object.values(items).reduce(mapIt, new Map),
        ([USERS, { sum, count }]) => ({ USERS, USAGE: sum / count })
    ));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```